# How to do a grandparent query?

Tags: soql

I am trying to get all leadless payments that are attached to a subscription given that subscription does not have a null lead, but if you see my query below, it only achieves half of the goal.

It gets all leadless payments that are attached to a subscription but I also need to ensure it retrieves records for those subscriptions who also do not have a null lead. How would I do such a subquery?

```
SELECT Id, Subscription__c FROM Payment__c
WHERE Lead__c = NULL AND Subscription__c != NULL
```

Comment: can u add details on how all these 3 objects (Payment, Lead and Subscription) are related to each other ?

Comment: @VamsiKrishna Lead can have subscriptions and payments. A payment can have a lead and a subscription. A subscription can have a payment and a lead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In soql you can reference grandparent as follows:

```
AND Subscription__r.Lead__c != null
```

You might just want to create a checkbox formula  and query on that instead.

```
AND(
    ISNULL(Lead__c),
    NOT(ISNULL(Subscription__r.Lead__c))
)
```

Comment: Excellent answer

Comment: @AliGajani Was my interpretation correct? I think your OP left some people guessing.

Comment: Yes. I clarified further below Vamsi's question on my OP. :)

Comment: @AliGajani If this answer [addressed your problem](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers), please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234) by clicking on the check mark/tick to the left of the answer, turning it green. This marks the question as resolved to your satisfaction, and awards [reputation](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) both to you and the person who answered. If you have >= 15 reputation points, you may also upvote the answer if you wish. There is no obligation to do either.

Comment: I did, thanks. By the way, how do I retrieve the Email on a Lead object in this very query. I would love to have that too. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Anywhere you have `Lead__c`, you can also get `Lead__r.Email`. Similar to how the above pulls `Lead__c` from `Subscription__r`.

Comment: okay I tried `SELECT Id, Lead__r.Email, Product_Purchase__c, Amount__c, Currency__c FROM Payment__c WHERE Lead__c = NULL AND Product_Purchase__c != NULL AND Product_Purchase__r.Lead__c != NULL AND Amount__c > 10` but I get (null Lead__r)` in the column.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43524/discussion-between-adrian-larson-and-ali-gajani).

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like you don't need a subquery, but instead need an OrderBy clause based on the value of `Lead__c` with something like `Nulls first`. What I hear you saying is that you want data returned for both when `Lead__c` is null and when it isn't.

```
SELECT Id, Subscription__c, Lead__c FROM Payment__c WHERE Subscription__c != NULL 
    ORDER BY Lead__c ASC NULLS FIRST
```

Now you can sort your results and split the list where the nulls end if you need to.

Comment: I think it's parent `Lead` is null but grandparent `Lead` (via `Subscription`) is not. Not 100% sure but that's my interpretation.

Comment: That part wasn't clear in his question. He didn't answer @VamsiKrishna question to add that clarification. In either case, he's still not doing a subquery.

Comment: The only way to access a lead is via subscription, because leadless payments dont have leads. This query won't work as its querying for lead existence on payment, something which is already implied.

Comment: Then you may still want to add the OrderBy clause to @AdrianLarson answer to help you separate the two types of payments.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT Id, Subscription__c FROM Payment__c WHERE Lead__c = NULL OR 
Subscription__c != NULL

Comment: Please add explanation and not just a code dump.

Comment: Can you please tell me your object relationship? means how they are related to eachother.